# Question about a theoretical bee's power to lift

Tags: drag, estimation, aerodynamics, air, lift

Given a theoretical bee with sufficient (not limited) wing power and material strength of the wing, but with realistic dimensions is it possible for it to lift a human?

If not, what are the limitations? Where is the bottleneck? I would assume it would have to do with properties of aerodynamics changing after a threshold.

Comment: Is the question if you could scale up a bee to human mass and have it still fly?

Comment: No, the size remains.

Comment: Do you mean could a normal-sized bee lift a human's weight by just basically beating its wings faster?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Of course an additional wing strength would probably be required.

Answer (score 2):

A big limitation here is probably the speed of sound. To get more lift of the wings you could probably just beat them faster, but (without doing any hard calculations) I can't imagine that you can beat a bee's wings fast enough to produce that much lift.

As a hand wave argument we can compare the **area** of the wings to the **mass** they are lifting. Commercial jets fly at about 80% of the speed of sound. A [Boeing 747](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747) has a wing area of 511m$^2$ and a maximum takeoff weight of 320,000 kg. That's 622 kg/m$^2%

Let's say the bee's wings have an area of 1 cm$^2$ (probably generous) and that it's lifting a 50kg human, that's $50{\rm kg}/(0.0001 \rm m^2) = 500,000 kg/m^2$, literally a factor of 1,000 more lift required per unit area, so probably impossible.

Comment: I was actually afraid that the characteristics of aerodynamics, namely the surface-to-weight ration "required for flight" would change along with the scale of things.. Just a thought.